# Remove new line character (merge two line into one) in specific line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file coming from 3rd party system which I need to correct a little bit. From time to time upcoming file contains a new line character in the middle of the data. Let's say that I'm able to find this corrupted line. What I need to do is simply to remove new line character and join the line with the line above (this will happen when I'll get rid of new line character).
Here is the example:

```
data_1 data_2 data_3 data_4 data_5
data_1 data_2 data_3 data_4 data_5
data_1 data_2 
 data_3 data_4 data_5
data_1 data_2 data_3 data_4 data_5
data_1 data_2 data_3 data_4 data_5
data_1 data_2 data_3 data_4 data_5
```

As you can see line number 3 is wrong and needs to be fixed/joined with line 4 by removing new line character.
I have a simple script which is able to find 'wrong' (too short) line. 
The question is: how to remove a new line character from a specific line (I have a wrong line number).

I tried with sed (`sed ':a;N;$!ba;3s/\n/ /' data.log`) where 3 before `s` is a line number but it's not working.

... or maybe there is a better solution for this problem. Please help.

Comment: Is there a space at the start of the line iff there is a superfluous newline?

Comment: yes. There is a 'space' at the begginig of next line (the one which is following wrong line).

Comment: can you count on the space always being there in the case of "corruption" ? :-)  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using sed, taking advantage of the space at the start of the new line

```
sed -e '{
N
s/\n //
}' data.log
```

This doesn't require you to know in advance where the spurious newlines are, but will only correct one break (as in it doesn't work if the line is split into 3)

Comment: Hah great idea. It's a shame that I did not come with this idea by myself :-). Indeed space will be always in front of new line when corrupted line is above. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> how to remove a new line character from a specific line (I have a
>   wrong line number)

If you have figured out the target line number then using awk you can do this:

```
awk -v N=3 '{if (NR==N) l=$0; else if (NR==N+1) print l $0; else print}' infile
```

Comment: Great it's working but I read that awk is quite slow. I read that awk needs to read the whole file before starting processing. My upcoming file can be quite big. Anyway many thanks for working solution :-).

Comment: Your assumption about awk is not correct. awk or sed will behave at pretty much same speed here.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really what you asked for, but it will automatically find corrupted rows and fix them. Just set how many column you expect, by setting `col` parameter

```
awk -v col=5 '
           { 
               if ((cur + NF) < col) 
               { 
                   printf($0); 
                   cur=cur+NF; 
               } 
               else 
               { 
                   print $0; 
                   cur=0; 
               } 
           }' your_file
```